# Significance of parameter on cointegrating vector

Tags: cointegration, bias-correction

I have been reading Section 6.2 (page 96) of this [manual](http://time-series.net/yahoo_site_admin/assets/docs/SupplementaryManual_all.117125921.pdf), where a procedure called "fully modified least squares" is discussed, and was developed on a paper of Phillips and Hansen (1990)
. The idea as I understand is that given an estimated cointegrating relationship, say:

\begin{equation}
y_t = \dot{\beta_0} + \dot{\beta_1}x_t + \dot{\beta_2}z_t + \epsilon_t \quad (1)
\end{equation}

we would like to conduct usual inferences on the $\beta$ vector. However our estimation of the standard error of the coefficients is problematic since we have jointly determined variables and probably serially correlated errors. A way to remedy this is to estimate an equation of the form:

$$y_t = \tilde{\beta}_0 + \tilde{\beta}_1x_t + \tilde{\beta}_2z_t + \sum_{i=-k_1}^{k_2} \alpha_i \Delta x_{t-i}+ \sum_{i=-l_1}^{l_2} \psi_i \Delta z_{t-i} + e_t \quad (2)$$

(i.e. including lagged and future differences of the regressors), then conduct yet again an autoregressive model on these errors:

$$e_t = \sum_{i=1}^{p}\gamma_i e_{t-i} + \eta_t$$

Now, save the variance of $\eta_t$ (lets denote it by $\sigma_{\eta}$). Finally, the "correct" standard deviation that we should use to do inferences on our vector $\beta$ is $\lambda=\sigma_{\eta}/(1-\sum_{i=1}^{p}\gamma_i)$.

Everything is ok so far, with some exceptions. I don't understand how we shall proceed on evaluating the hypothesis $H_0 : \hat{\beta_i}= \beta_i$ (some value). I mean, according to the manual, we now can compute:

$$t=\frac{\hat{\dot{\beta_i}} - \beta_i}{\lambda}$$

and then evaluate as usual whether this exceeds some critical value. My concrete questions are: which estimated $\beta$ are we using as our point estimate, $\hat{\dot{\beta}}_i$ (of equation 1) or $\hat{\tilde{\beta}}_i$ (of equation 2)? And a second and final question, the standard error used in the test doesn't seem correct to me, in the senese that it is the same for both regressors.

Could someone help me understand better this method?

Comment: Hi: I think you would use the estimates from equation (2) since that handles the problems you mentioned. For for the second question, are you sure that it says to use $\sigma_{\eta$ in the denominator. That doesn't feel correct to me either. I'll check out page 96 and see if anything becomes clearer ?

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I feel like the author has some sort of typo. It should be dividing by the st. deviation of the parameter, which I think is actually (for the parameter of our $x$ variable: $\sigma_{\eta}/\sqrt{S_{xx}}$ where $S_{xx}$ is the sum of squares of $x_i$'s. What do you think? Could you look at the link? @mlofton

Comment: Hi:  I'm not expert enough on this material ( maybe I could have been like 10 years ago )  to say anything with certainty but my best guess is that the test statistic should be $\frac{\hat{\beta}_{1} - \beta_{1}}{\lambda}$. I say this because, based on what he says to do, the scale factor, $\sigma_{e}$ would get cancelled out. I would think there might be some econometrics textbook that would go into FIML in greater detail ?

Comment: The other problem is that, in the Ender's example, there is just one coefficient, $z_t$, where, in your case, you have two coefficients. I'm not sure on how that changes things in ender's discussion. There are so many decent time series econometrics texts but I'm not sure which one has the best coverage of FIML ? Maybe Davidson or Hamilton or Hayashi ? Or even Wooldridge ? I moved so all of my time series econometrics texts are in storage. Otherwise, I'd take a look. I really this isn't terribly helpful but I would look at another better discussion before I followed the procedure he describes.

Comment: Edited my post! @mlofton. You are right that $\lambda$ should be the one in the denominator. But if we stopped in case 2 and there were no more problems (all OLS assumption are satisfied) then we should be able to implement usual t-tests and definetively standard errors of coeficients do not need to be identical.

Comment: Sarah: I just googled for "introduction to full information maximum likelihood in cointegration framework" and a lot of things come up. The famous paper is the one in 1990 by Johansen and Julius. But, to be honest, it looks REALLY COMPLICATED. I did find two others that look more readable ( atleast to me ) and I'll put their links in the next comment.

Comment: Hi Sarah: This is a kinder explanation ( compared to the 1990 demand for money paper ) by Johansen. https://www.fsb.miamioh.edu/lij14/672_johansen.pdf. This one is by Eric Zivot. https://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ582/cointegrationtestingandestimatingslides.pdf. Note that I still think the best thing to do would be to find a text that has a discussion of FIML. Note that  the FIML procedure is also going to depend on whether you're using the engle granger approach or Johansen-Julius ? Assuming you have more than two variables, then I would think that you'd need to use the latter.